# How to magnify display working with pixels[] in Processing (Java)?

Tags: java, processing, pixel

I love experimenting with operating on images pixel by pixel using [pixels[]](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html). However, I’d like to work on a matrix of 100x100 pixels but have the display be several times larger than 100x100 on my screen.

**Is there an efficient and straightforward way to zoom, magnify, scale, resize, or etc… to allow me to work with pixels[] just… bigger?**

I was disappointed to see that scale() doesn’t work with pixel arrays.

My first idea to scale by a factor of S is by iterating through my pixel array and drawing a board of SxS `rect`s with the fill of each pixel’s color val. However, this is computationally intensive, and I can’t get my frameRate above 5 or so.

Comment: Is there any issue with rendering to pixels to a 100x100 image, then just resize it as normal, but set the rendering hints to use nearest-neighbour to keep it crisp?

Answer (score 2):

Ah great idea @sorifiend. Since I was calling loadPixels() immediately after setting the window size() and leaving it blank (rather than loading pixels from a image and putting it in the window,) I hadn't thought of that. **I found you can use [createImage()](https://processing.org/reference/createImage_.html) to make an empty image, which resizes crisply with noSmooth(); on!** Thanks for the start.

Here's my code for posterity:

```
void setup() {
  i = createImage(100, 100, RGB);
  background(0);
  size(800, 800);
  i.loadPixels();
  noSmooth();

}

void draw() {
  i.loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x < i.width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < i.height; y++) {
      if (random(0,max(i.width,i.height)) < y) {
        i.pixels[x + y*i.height] = color(255);
      } else {
        i.pixels[x + y*i.height] = color(0);
      }
    }
  }
  i.updatePixels();
  image(i,0,0,width,height);
}
```